# How to get email Id of authenticated user?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

My azure web app is authenticated by Microsoft Account login. I enabled it through Azure portal with changing authentication/authorization settings of web app.This does not need any change in web app code. And authentication part is working fine.

Now I want the email Id of the user who gets authenticated before accessing the web app.

I tried to read `User.Identity` as `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal`. But this is coming as null.

How to access the email Id of authenticated user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your webapp and click `Authentication / Authorization`.Under Authentication providers, click on `Microsoft Account`. Click on `wl.basic` & `wl.emails` to enable them.

[image]

Then go to `ExternalLoginCallback` and add the following code:

```
var identity = await AuthenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
var emailClaim = identity.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email);
var email = emailClaim.Value;
```

The code result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. Where is this ExternalLoginCallback method?

Comment: In AccountController.

Comment: I create an asp.net signal page application.

Comment: My web app is an old solution with "No Authentication" selected while creation. Now I have to implement Microsoft authentication. I added all required nuget packages. Still loginInfo is null in my case. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I am now able to get authenticated user email, even though my asp.net mvc app was initially "No Authentication" app. I enabled MS authentication from the Azure portal for my web app. Now I fetch user email from System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims object. It is automatically set by MS authentication flow.